# Android - firebase notifications behaviour

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, notifications

As far as I understand regarding Firebase push notifications:

1. When the user taps on a notification while the app is closed the notification data arrives to the launch screen.
2. If the app is in foreground, the notification is fetched in the `onMessageReceived` method from the service that overrides `FirebaseMessagingService`

But... what I need to detect is...

When a notification has been received but the user didn't enter into the app tapping on it but clicking on the app icon.

I need to display a countdown popup when the notification is received, but in that case (clicking on the icon) I have no information about the received notification.